# How do I build these libraries from GitHub

Tags: android, build, showcaseview

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to build a jar of the [Showcase View library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) so that I can import it into my application.

I've searched all around but can't find a process for it.  I tried importing into Eclipse but I can't get it in there since it isn't a project and I'm not sure what type of project to create from source with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Library Projects http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way is:

1. Create an empty Android Application project in your Eclipse workspace.
2. Copy files in ShowcaseView/library/ folder of github to your new project base folder.
3. Refresh project in Eclipse.
4. Goto project properties - Android and select "Is Library"
5. Clean unnecessary stuff and build.

It should be ready to add as dependency of your app.

Alternatively you can pick another library project .project file and copy it inside this library folder, edit it to match your new project name, etc... And then import in Eclipse. But this is more hardcore if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: That was perfect and way easier than I thought it would be.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not getting the functions used in the library, It has been imported without any problem. But I can't use those functions.

Comment: harshit: It seems to me that you didn't add the dependency of the library on your main project, am I right?