# How do I import ShowcaseView in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, showcaseview

`ShowcaseView` is contained in a Zip file [here](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView). But what exactly am I downloading and how do I import it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 21):

After 2 days I succeed, I have created steps to import [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview) in Eclipse that may be helpful to you.

How to use Showcase View in Eclipse.

1. Download [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview) from github and extract.
2. Now Follow [step for import](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2iaquxf.jpg).

   ```
   - Right click on Project Explorer
   - Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace
   - Select Extracted "ShowcaseView-master"
   - Check both project "library" and "MainActivity"
   - Check "Copy projects into workspace"
   - Finish.
   ```

   (After importing you can see 2 projects imported namely "main" and "SampleActivity", you may change "main" as "**libShowcaseView**" and "SampleActivity" as "**ShowcaseViewDemo**" so you can easily identify. :) )
3. May you see error in "ShowcaseViewDemo" (Dont worry...), See `src/` folder is also blank (in both "[libShowcaseView](https://s27.postimg.cc/kx002z2xf/image.png)" and "[ShowcaseViewDemo](https://s27.postimg.cc/4aiftw9zn/image.png)") :) right??? Dont mind.
4. Make following packages in **"libShowcaseView"** project. [See Example.](https://s18.postimg.cc/lf94lzgmh/image.png)

   ```
   - com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview
   - com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.targets
   ```

   and **Move all java files** from `/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview` and `/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/targets` Respectively.
5. Make following packages in "ShowcaseViewDemo" project. [See Example.](https://s18.postimg.cc/swic1765l/image.png)

   ```
   - com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.sample
   - com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.sample.animations
   - com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.sample.legacy
   - com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.sample.v14
   ```

   and **move files as above (from java folder respectively)**.
6. Now right click on **"libShowcaseView"** project->properties->Android->Move down and **check "Is Library"** then add **"actionbarsherlock"** as Library. [See Preview](https://s28.postimg.cc/650ufgep9/image.png)
7. Now Add as library in ShowcaseViewDemo. Goto properties of **"ShowcaseViewDemo"->Android->Add->select "libShowcaseView"->Ok...**
8. I think you didn't ran into error now. You can Run.

You can ping any time for any suggestion or help.

Happy ShowcaseViewing...

Comment: Thank you for this tutorial :) Just a reminder: If you follow these steps, you need to install the actionbarsherlock lib. You just have to clone it, import it as android project in eclipse (Check "Copy projects into workspace"). That's it ! This library is available here : https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Android v7 support library can also be used in place of ActionbarSherlock

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is:

1. Create an empty Android Application project in your Eclipse workspace.
2. Copy files in ShowcaseView/library/ folder of github to your new project base folder.
3. Refresh project in Eclipse.
4. Goto project properties - Android and select "Is Library"
5. Clean unnecessary stuff and build.

It should be ready to add as dependency of your app.

Alternatively you can pick another library project .project file and copy it inside this library folder, edit it to match your new project name, etc... And then import in Eclipse. But this is more hardcore if you don't know what you're doing.
Soure : [How do I build these libraries from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473893/how-do-i-build-these-libraries-from-github)

Answer (score 1):

Following **ツ Pratik Butani ツ's Answer** and use **Android Support Library** to replace **ActionBarSherlock**

1. In **project.properties** of **libShowcaseView** and **ShowcaseViewDemo**

   - add `target=android-21`
2. Right click on **"libShowcaseView"** **Properties->Android->Library->Add... select AppCompat(android support library v7)->Ok**
3. In **styles.xml** of **ShowcaseViewDemo**

   - Change 
     `android:Theme.Holo.Light`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` to  `Theme.AppCompat`
   - Remove `<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>` in `ListItemBigText`
4. In **ActionItemsSampleActivity.java**

   - change `SherlockActivity` to `ActionBarActivity`, `getSupportMenuInflater` to `getMenuInflater`.
5. In **MultipleActionItemsSampleActivity.java**

   - change `SherlockActivity` to `ActionBarActivity`
   - change `com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener` to `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener`
   - change`getSupportMenuInflater` to `getMenuInflater`

Answer (score 1):

Do it in there steps:

1. Download ShowcaseView from  [github](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview)`
2. Create package `com.github.amlcurran.schowcaseview` and `com.github.amlcurran.schowcaseview.targets` in your eclipse project.
3. Extract `ShowcaseView-master.zip` or rar.
4. Go to `library/src/main/java/ and copy com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview` java files in `com.github.amlcurran.schowcaseview` package.
5. Do same thing for `com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/targets` in `com.github.amlcurran.schowcaseview.targets`.
6. Finally, copy others files in differents folder `drawables, layouts, value`(copy in the old value files, style.xml for example).